# Current date and time in Soy file

Tags: google-closure

Is there any way to get the current date and time in the Soy template itself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident you cannot do this. It's possible you could implement your own [custom function](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/plugins#functions), but it will probably be much easier to simply pass in the current date/time string as a parameter to your template.